# How to fix page scrolling down in IE7 when clicking an anchor inside an iframe?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I have an iframe with an anchor inside. clicking this anchor calls the top page function to do work. but when clicking it, IE7 scrolls down the top page.
How Do I keep the scrolling position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused if attribute href="#" is set for the anchor.

To fix this, remove this attribute.

To keep the pointer style cursor after that, set its style in CSS.